# Copying file(s) with drag and drop from Qt 5.2 application to file system

Tags: drag-and-drop, mime-types, qt5, qt5.2

How do I go about generating a file drag and drop operation in a Qt 5.2 application that performs a copy (or move) in the file system (Windows, Mac, etc.)? More specifically: Generate a drag with 1+ file paths that will perform a copy/move on those files when dropped onto the system.

Is there a standard mime-type I can use for this - providing file paths as mime data?

Answer (score 0):

[QMimeData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#setUrls) has a functionality to add a **text/uri-list**.

To drag/drop a file onto the system add a [QUrl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QUrl.html) that starts with **file:///** followed by your path.

```
QList<QUrl> urls;

list.append(QUrl("file:///path");

QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData;

mimeData->setUrls(list);
```

Comment: Could you provide some detail or explanation for your answer?

Comment: The event made available throught the parameter list of dragEnterEvent has a member function mimeData(). Use this instead of creating a new QMimeData object that connects to nothing relevant.

Comment: A quick piece of advice: You probably want to use `QUrl::fromLocalFile(const QString &localFile)` to create your `QUrl` instances. It abstracts away the complexity of encoding the path properly.