# MPC-HC player recognizable mime data while dropping subtitles from Qt application

Tags: c++, media-player, qt5, mime-types, windows-7-x64

As a part of my application,I have a QListWidget with subtitle file names.My intention is to add a subtitles to the player by dragging items from the list widget to the player.I have sub classed the list widget  and Mime data is defined as

```
        QStringList mimeTypes() const
        {
            QStringList typelists;
            typelists.append("text/uri-list");
            return typelists;
        }
        QMimeData * mimeData( const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items ) const
        {
            QMimeData *data = new QMimeData();
            QList< QUrl > urls;
            QUrl url;
            QString path=( tr("G:/videos/subs/%1").arg(items[0]->text()) );
            url=QUrl::fromLocalFile(path);
            qDebug() << url.path();
            urls.append( url );
            data->setUrls( urls );
            return data;
        }
```

It works perfectly for VLC player ,but MPC-HC throws "file not found" error.I have tried

> mime type as text/plain                          --> Works for VLC
>
> mime type as text/uri-list                          --> Works for VLC
>
> Tried with file:////path as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839932/copying-files-with-drag-and-drop-from-qt-5-2-application-to-file-system/24478800#24478800)  --> Didn't work

Is there any standard mimetype that all the media players are supposed to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine with the new version MPC-HC 1.7.7 (x64).Probably a bug in the earlier versions